# Husky simulator on Lunar: source code

Tags: ros-lunar, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find husky simulator package source code to compile it to Lunar distribution?

There are other questions about it, telling that we can compile from source, but they don't tell where the source code is and searching on Internet I haven't found it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296322/husky-simulator-on-lunar:-source-code/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q295677.

Summarising:

- for released and indexed pkgs: go to wiki page ([wiki/husky_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_simulator)), click on *Source* link in the *Package Summary* section (typically top of the page)
- alternatively: setup debian source repositories and use `apt-get source`
- for everything else (ie: not released, no wiki page): search for the package name with Google and look for the source repository (typically hosted on Github)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-07-05**:
Thanks but, what do I have to do to compile it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:
Please see #q252478: it talks about Kinetic and 16.04, but the process is the same on Lunar. You obviously don't want to do the `git clone ..` step if you've already retrieved the sources using some other method.